# Taxonomy navigation in DXA 2.0 throws exception

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, dxa-net

I am implementing a taxonmy based navigation in SDL Web 8.5 with DXA 2.0. According to the documentation, I have created a category keyword with [Navigation] in its title.

[image]

I have published this Category and Keyword as well. 
In Unity.config, I have changed the mapping for INavigationProvider from Static to Dynamic as well.

```
 <type type="INavigationProvider" mapTo="DynamicNavigationProvider">
          <lifetime type="singleton" />
 </type>
```

I expect to see NavigationLinks model to be populated. However, it never happens. I put some code in try and catch to see what is the exception.

```
public static NavigationLinks GetDynamicNavigationLinks(this HtmlHelper helper,string requestUrlPath,Localization localization)
        {
            try
            {
                INavigationProvider navigationProvider = SiteConfiguration.NavigationProvider;
                var navigationLinks = navigationProvider.GetTopNavigationLinks(requestUrlPath, localization);
                return navigationLinks;
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }

        }
```

The exception is as follows:

```
    2018-07-20 09:47:30,826 [9] DEBUG - No value cached for key 'GetNavigationModel:17' in region 'Navigation_Dynamic'.
2018-07-20 09:47:48,988 [9] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response for URL 'http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/':
DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response from request 'http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/api/navigation/17' of . 
2018-07-20 09:47:49,337 [9] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response.
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response. ---> Sdl.Web.ModelService.ModelServiceException: DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response from request 'http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/api/navigation/17' of . ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Sdl.Web.ModelService.ModelServiceClient.PerformRequest[T](IModelServiceRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.ModelService.ModelServiceClient.PerformRequest[T](IModelServiceRequest request)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.DefaultModelServiceProvider.GetSitemapItem(Localization localization)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.DefaultModelServiceProvider.GetSitemapItem(Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.ModelServiceImpl.DynamicNavigationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<GetNavigationModel>b__0()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.ModelServiceImpl.DynamicNavigationProvider.GetNavigationModel(Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.ModelServiceImpl.DynamicNavigationProvider.GetBreadcrumbNavigationLinks(String requestUrlPath, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.DynamicNavigationProvider.GetBreadcrumbNavigationLinks(String requestUrlPath, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.NavigationController.Navigation(EntityModel entity, String navType, Int32 containerSize)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2018-07-20 09:53:35,466 [9] DEBUG - No value cached for key 'GetNavigationModel:17' in region 'Navigation_Dynamic'.
2018-07-20 09:53:52,372 [9] ERROR - DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response for URL 'http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/':
DXA Model Service returned an unexpected response from request 'http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/api/navigation/17' of .
```

When I make the Get request to the Navigation API however, I get the data:
Get -> http://webcmsnd.[domainName].org:8998/api/navigation/17

```
{
   "Id":"t25583",
   "Type":"TaxonomyNode",
   "Title":"Dynamic [Navigation]",
   "OriginalTitle":"Dynamic [Navigation]",
   "Visible":false,
   "Items":[
      {
         "$type":"TaxonomyNodeModelData",
         "Id":"t25583-k232401",
         "Type":"TaxonomyNode",
         "Title":"Home",
         "OriginalTitle":"000 Home",
         "Visible":false,
         "Items":[
            {
               "$type":"TaxonomyNodeModelData",
               "Id":"t25583-k232404",
               "Type":"TaxonomyNode",
               "Title":"Articles",
               "OriginalTitle":"010 Articles",
               "Visible":false,
               "Items":[

               ],
               "Key":"010 Articles",
               "HasChildNodes":false,
               "Description":"Articles",
               "IsAbstract":false,
               "ClassifiedItemsCount":0
            }
         ],
         "Key":"000 Home",
         "HasChildNodes":true,
         "Description":"Home",
         "IsAbstract":false,
         "ClassifiedItemsCount":0
      },
      {
         "$type":"TaxonomyNodeModelData",
         "Id":"t25583-k232402",
         "Type":"TaxonomyNode",
         "Title":"Resource",
         "OriginalTitle":"010 Resource",
         "Visible":false,
         "Items":[

         ],
         "Key":"010 Resource",
         "HasChildNodes":false,
         "Description":"Resource",
         "IsAbstract":false,
         "ClassifiedItemsCount":0
      },
      {
         "$type":"TaxonomyNodeModelData",
         "Id":"t25583-k232403",
         "Type":"TaxonomyNode",
         "Title":"News",
         "OriginalTitle":"020 News",
         "Visible":false,
         "Items":[

         ],
         "Key":"020 News",
         "HasChildNodes":false,
         "Description":"News",
         "IsAbstract":false,
         "ClassifiedItemsCount":0
      }
   ],
   "Key":"",
   "HasChildNodes":false,
   "Description":"",
   "IsAbstract":true,
   "ClassifiedItemsCount":0
}
```

I further investigated this issue and found out that the cause of error is ModelServiceClient.cs in PerformRequest method. For reasons that are unknown to me, the request times out on request.GetResponse(). The same request can be made on PostMan or browser and the JSON formatted data returns as expected.

[image]

Line 199 in ModelServiceClient.cs is where the timeout exception happens.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why the request times out on request.GetResponse()? (it is probably an infrastructure issue, what is that?)
2. How can I customize the category keyword navigation to add customized
   fields and publishing them as JSON?

Comment: The cause of the exception is that the Model Service returned an unexpected response. If you set log level to DEBUG, you should be able to see the Model Service request and response. Furthermore, the Model Service log file might reveal the issue.

Comment: @RickPannekoek Log level is already set to DEBUG. The log that I have attached is the result of that.

Comment: I only see one ERROR line, though. I’m not asking to include the entire debug log, though. Just explaining how you can dive deeper yourself.

Comment: @RickPannekoek I added more to the log. However, I am more concerned that if I am missing a step in the process of getting this dynamic navigation data. Looking at the documentation, it seems that I have taken all the steps.

Comment: I doubt that the problem lies in missing a step. You should dive deeper to find the root cause of the exception. Unfortunately, debug logging reveals less than I expected. I think the Model Service request URL path is `/api/navigation/17`

Comment: @RickPannekoek I did some more investigation and updated the question. I believe that this is an infrastructure issue.

Comment: Anything interesting in the Model Service log? Try with log level set to DEBUG.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging, I made the following changes to the request object in ModelServiceCleint.cs

[image]

Lines 162 and 163 were added. This time the request didn't timeout and I got the response back. Obviously, this is not a solution, but just isolating the root cause. There must be a performance issue on the DXA service side.

Comment: Nice that you managed to demystify the issue and find a work-around. Please do report this isssue on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues).  That is: unclear error handling (why doesn’t it say there was a timeout) and lack of ability to configure the timeout (?).

Comment: I hope you will continue your quest regarding the performance issue (maybe with help from SDL Customer Support)? Is your Taxonomy very large?